# Rails two registration forms with two user types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I have a rails project where I have one user model with two different roles one is for a client and the other for business, currently am playing around with both enum roles and rolify.

I am using devise as my authentication system and I have two registration forms for each one but what I want to achieve is to assign the role to the user after the create action so to give him the ability afterwards to create a client profile or a business profile and more ..., I don't want to give the user the ability to choose from a select what type he wants.

So I am bit confused I used this method before :

```
after_initialize :set_client, :if => :new_record?
def set_client
    self.kind ||= :client
end
```

I know this will give every record a client role, so I wanted to do it on the controllers and I hear its bad practice.

So am thinking to pass a hidden field in the form with the value of the role.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why do you think that handling this in the controller is a bad practice? Hidden field in the form can be easily modified by the client that creates a new account when the code in the controller is much safer.

Comment: while searching something about that came across, can you mention some code to achieve this on the controller side, I failed doing it every time.

Comment: Can you add a controllers code that you use for creating new user and business profiles?

Comment: Please update your question with the code from controllers

Comment: Sorry I am having an issue posting all the code on the comment.
So basically I have a User model with all personal information first name, last name, email, password and an enum : enum kind: [:client, :business]

a user has_one :client_profile and has_one :business_profile.
both client_profile and business_profile belongs_to :user

the ability to create a client profile or a business profile will be set later by pundit to give the authorization to the right user.
for the user registration controller it's a devise controller with a custom methods to get client and business and post them

Comment: I wanted to say if you have two separate form then you don't worry about that, you just add two hidden  input field for these